# Link Syncronised Data Extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Does Marketing Cloud support a way, without the use of SQL query automation to link up several Syncronised Data Extensions (from Sales Cloud) so a single table could be used to create filtered Data Extensions?

The Classic Data Filter Join scenario seems to apply for regular Data Extensions exclusively - [link](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_filters/multi_join_filters/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create Data Relationships as described in the link you supplied, as these also work with Synchronized Data Extensions. If you want multiple sources of data combined into a single Data Extension though, that would have to be done with SQL queries.